# How to DUMP the full hexa of each function extracted by analysis of binary file?

Tags: python, radare2, capstone

I used a script python from radare2-bindings to write a code analysing a binary file, i extracted the name , the start address and the size of each function , but i can't dump the hexa of each function , i am asking if there is a methode or python script in radare2 or another tool (capstone , miasm , angr ...)  to solve this problem .

the script is :

```
    import sys
    import sqlite3 as lite
    try:
        import os, signal
        from r_core import *
    except:
        from r2.r_core import *

    rc = RCore()
    rc.file_open("/home/younes/Bureau/a.out", 0, 0)
    rc.bin_load("", 0)

    rc.anal_all()
    funcs = rc.anal.get_fcns()
    for f in funcs:
        blocks = f.get_bbs()
        print("+" + (72 * "-"))
        print("| FUNCTION: %s @ 0x%x" % (f.name, f.addr))
        print("| (%d blocks)" % (len (blocks)))
        print("+" + (72 * "-"))
        funcSize=0
        for b in blocks:
            end_byte = b.addr + b.size
            cur_byte = b.addr
            funcSize+=b.size

        print("   | f.size:      0x%x" %(funcSize))

    os.kill (os.getpid (), signal.SIGTERM)
```

Comment: What does your "I can't" mean, in this context? Do regular Python file operations not work in this environment, don't you have direct access to the raw data ... or, literally, *you* can't do it because you don't know how to?

Comment: yes i don't know how to access to the raw data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already resolved on github repository: https://github.com/radare/radare2-bindings/issues/130#issuecomment-233662221

```
import r2pipe
import sys

r2 = r2pipe.open(sys.argv[1])
r2.cmdj("aaa") # http://radare.today/posts/analysis-by-default/
function_list = r2.cmdj("aflj") # Analysis Function List Json

for function in function_list:
    print r2.cmdj("p8j" + str(function["size"])+ " @ " + function["name"] ) # 8bit hexpair Json
```

Comment: thank you it already works , but what about address ?  print("funcAddrs 0x%x" + %(function["address"])) ?

Comment: print("0x%x"%(function['offset']))